# How to Sort Data time stamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime, max

I have an array with date time stamp. The format is eg. 11/6/2015 15-47-35.501

I have to get the maximum/ latest DateTime stamp from this array. So applied the logic of sorting but not working. And I have to take this format only otherwise previous records will not work If I take other formats.

Code snippet is

```
function somefunction()
{
var creation_dt_newarr = ["11/6/2015 15-47-35.501","11/6/2015 16-19-32.939","11/6/2015 18-31-31.343"]

  creation_dt_newarr = creation_dt_arr.sort(sortFunction);
  var replaced_data = creation_dt_newarr[creation_dt_newarr.length-1];
                        var max_creation_dt_res = replaced_data;
}


function sortFunction(a,b){
    var dateA = new Date(a).getTime();
    var dateB = new Date(b).getTime();
    return dateA > dateB ? 1 : -1;
};
```

Please help me out how this will work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This date format is not supported by JavaScript, and `new Date(a)` will fail. I strongly suggest you save your dates as milliseconds since Epoch. Refactoring fully warranted. If you absolutely have to sort on this... it will be slow, since you will need to implement your own custom parsing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help:

```
function somefunction()
{
var creation_dt_newarr = ["11/6/2015 15-47-35.501","11/6/2015 16-19-32.939","11/6/2015 18-31-31.343"];
  //do some preprocessing if that is OK the last three digits like: .501
  creation_dt_newarr.forEach(function(element,i){
      creation_dt_newarr[i] = Date.parse(element.slice(0,-4).replace(/-/g,':')); 
  });
  //use Math.max to get the max date and 
  //to get the result as a date string use the new Date()
  return new Date(Math.max.apply(null, creation_dt_newarr));
}

console.log(somefunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that date to a format that works. On the Google Chrome console, I tried creating a date in your format:

```
new Date('11/6/2015 15-47-35.501')
Invalid Date
```

However, if you replace the `-` and `.` in the time part with `:`, it does parse the date:

```
new Date('11/6/2015 15-47-35.501'.replace(/[-.]/g, ':'));
Fri Nov 06 2015 15:47:35 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Based on that, we can adapt your sort function to:

```
function sortFunction(a,b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.replace(/[-.]/g, ':')).getTime();
    var dateB = new Date(b.replace(/[-.]/g, ':')).getTime();
    return dateA > dateB ? 1 : -1;
};
```

I am not certain the time is being parsed correctly -- I'm assuming the last part after the period is milliseconds. You should confirm it is being parsed correctly and as the commenter suggested, storing the time as a timestamp would of course be nicer.